# .htaccess Redirect a query string to another page using the query string value

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have spent a great many hours trying to find a solution to this and tried many different approches but nothing I have tried has worked so far.

I would like to redirect a URL with query string to another URL that contains the value of that query string.

For example:-
http://site.co.uk/module/filecatalogue/downloads?cid=value
would redirect to
http://site.co.uk/module/filecatalogue/downloads/value

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am about to go insane.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cid=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.co.uk/module/filecatalogue/downloads/%1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

What this does is takes your variable `cid=` as a condition, if the server detects it in the URL it will move forward to the RewriteRule.

It will rewrite it using a 301 redirect to http://site.co.uk/module/filecatalogue/downloads/anything. Anything representing the variable, which is grabbed using `(.+)`.

We include a `?` at the end of the URL in order to stop the original query appearing on the end of the new URL.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: Thanks so much :-) 

I was close but wouldn’t have got there without your help.